# Java/CGAL verify if a graph is connected (some constraints in description)

Tags: java, graph, cgal

it's my first time with CGAL, some of you may argue why do I have to learn CGAL from something like that, but it's a new project that I must do (and... yes, I must use CGAL and Java combined) :/ Long story short... I only have:

- Two double arrays, representing x and y coordinates of my vertices. Let's call them `double[] x, y;`.
- Both arrays have `S` random values.
- Two vertices, `u` and `w` are connected if `distance(x[u], y[u], x[w], y[w]) < CONSTANT` (ofc. I do `distanceSquared(x[u], y[u], x[w], y[w]) < CONSTANT_SQUARED`, so I avoid to call sqrt()).
- `x` and `y` are filled randomly with values from `0` to `UPPER_LIMIT`, no other infos are given.

Question, do `x` and `y` describes a connected graph?

Right now I have two algoritms:

- Algorithm 1:

  1. Build adjacency list (`Arraylist<Integer>[] adjLists;`) for each vertex (only upper triangular matrix explored). Complexity `O(|V|^2)` (V = vertices set).
  2. Recursive graph exploration, vertex marking and counting, if visited vertex equals `S` my graph have only one connected component, my graph is connected. Complexity `O(|E|)` (E = edges set).
- Algorithm 2:

  ```
  private static boolean algorithmGraph(double[] x, double[] y) {
     int unchecked, inside = 0, current = 0;
     double switchVar;
     while (current <= inside && inside != S - 1) {
        unchecked = inside + 1;
        while (unchecked < S) {
           if ((x[current] - x[unchecked]) * (x[current] - x[unchecked]) + (y[current] - y[unchecked]) * (y[current] - y[unchecked]) <= CONSTANT_SQUARED) {
              inside++;
              // switch x coordinates | unchecked <-> inside
              switchVar = x[unchecked];
              x[unchecked] = x[inside];
              x[inside] = switchVar;
              // switch y coordinates | unchecked <-> inside
              switchVar = y[unchecked];
              y[unchecked] = y[inside];
              y[inside] = switchVar;
           }
           unchecked++;
        }
        current++;
     }
     return inside == S - 1;
  }
  ```

Funny thing the second one is slower, I do not use data structures, the code is iterative and in-place but the heavy use of switch makes it slow as hell.

The problem spec changed and now I must do it with CGAL and Java, I'll read the whole "https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings" to learn how to use CGAL within Java.... but I'd like some help about this specific instance of CGAL code... Are there faster algorithms already implemented in CGAL?

Thank you for your times guys! Happy coding!

Comment: Not only it's hard to understand what your second algo is trying to achieve, but is demonstrable buggy. Test it with `double x[]={1,2,3}`, `double y[]={0,0,0}`, `S=2` and `CONSTANT_SQUARED=4` - returned value is `false` even if no pair of points is separated by a distance > 2. **Happy debugging, Vento**- learn to write clear code, it will increase your chances to write good code.

Comment: Ups sorry I forgot to write `inside++` in the if-block before the switchVar. Ty to point that out. Btw `S` is the array lenght, so in your example should be 3.

Comment: The second alg try create a connected sub-graph, the vertices from index `0` to `inside` are contained in the sub-graph. If a node not in my sub-graph (`unchecked` index, from `inside + 1` to `S`), should be connected to my sub-graph (the range check, if block), I move this new node inside my sub-graph by switching the coordinates. The while-conditions are just boundaries checks and way to make the computations faster (if `inside == S - 1` my sub-graph is the whole graph so the graph is connected -> the first while can stop).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, without a method of *spatial indexing*, the best performance you are going to achieve in the worst-case-scenario (all connected) is going to be `O(n*(n-1)/2)`.

If you can afford to build a spatial index (have enough memory to pay for the boost in speed), you may consider [R-tree and variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) - insertion is `O(n)` searching is `O(log2(n))`: this will get your "outlier detection by examining distances" approach for a cost of of `O(n*log2(n))` in the worst-case-scenario.

**[A notable result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree#cite_note-7)**